# How to Show Seclected plist data in Second Tableview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, nsuserdefaults

In my Application i have Two Tableviews one is my main Tableview and Second one is my Favourit tableview.First of all i show all my plist data in mainView when i Click on any Row of my MainTableview it goes to Next Class as my Screen shot Show below
                               [image]

Now in this View i have a UILabel which show my Text  selected from main Tableview and most importantly i have UIButton Add to Favorit. i want that when i click on  it save the Current UIlabel Value and when i goes to favourit tableview then i want to show this value there.i try to save value using NSUserdefualt but it not works for me Beacuse it save the last value not keep the record of  pervious one values.here is my code which i tried so for..

```
 -(IBAction)AddToF
 {
    NSString *str=lblText.text;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:str forKey:@"preferenceName"];
 }
```

And then in Favurit tableview i get these value

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
     NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Can some guide me how to fix it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store array in userDefault instead of string like bellow..

In `AppDelegate.h` file just declare variable...

```
NSUserDefaults  *userDefaults;
NSMutableArray *yourArray;
after...
```

In `AppDelegate.m` Fille in `applicationDidFinishLonching:` Method

```
userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else {
    yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[yourArray retain];
```

after when you want to insert Data in this UserDefaults Use Bellow Code...

```
[appDelegate.yourArray addObject:yourDataString];///set your value or anything which you want to store here...
NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.yourArray];
[appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourArray"];
[appDelegate.userDefaults synchronize];
```

when you want to create `AppDelegate` object then use bellow code..

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but how to reterive value from it.

Comment: hey i see i get data from userdefault from oldsavearray same like .. just implement this logic where you want to get data and also just use appDelegate.yourArray try this :)

Comment: give me one error userDefaults undeclear [appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourArray"];
[appDelegate.userDefaults synchronize]; in these lines

Comment: oky i fix these errors by Setting its property Senthize it.but one thig still problm how to reterive these value in favourit tableview Class.

Comment: you property syntesize this both variable??

Comment: use this code just modify and store in your new table mutable array..NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [appDelegate.userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21510/discussion-between-lena-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: @lena hi, how r you?? when you will free then come on chat.. discussion on chat.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tell you the 3 easy steps.

1 - Read the Old Data from Saved Plist File

```
NSString *filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSLog(@"fav List = %@", array);
```

2 - Now in Add new Item using

```
  [array addObject:someItem];
```

3 - Save the Data in the plist

```
  [array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```